# Content policy in react google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, frontend, content-security-policy

Good day. Using `react-google-maps` with Streetview.

Locally, everything works fine

[Street view image on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp4vh.jpg)

But on production I see black screen

[Street view image on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EYj3.jpg)

In console log there is an error

`Refused to load the image 'https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=apiv3&panoid=FogDkTvJLazCtorobZljyA&output=tile&x=0&y=0&zoom=0&nbt&fover=2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' blob: data: https://*.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/".`

I tried to add this Content policy into `index.html` like:

```
 <head>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' blob: data: https://*.ggpht.com https://*.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/">
...
 </head>
```

But still has the same error with black screen on Streetview.
Do I miss something? Or maybe Content policy should be set up in another way?
P.S. tested this too https://content-security-policy.com/examples/google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin for Firefox to get required Content-security-policy

https://github.com/april/laboratory

```
default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';
font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com https://use.fontawesome.com;
img-src 'self' data: https://geo0.ggpht.com https://geo1.ggpht.com https://geo2.ggpht.com https://geo3.ggpht.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/common.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/controls.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/geometry.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/imagery_viewer.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/map.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/marker.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/onion.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/streetview.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/42/9/util.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeoPhotoService.GetMetadata https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeoPhotoService.SingleImageSearch https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jvectormap/2.0.4/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/
```